# Why is double integration of 1 representing area?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to understand why $\iint dA$ is the area of the region A.

I thought double integration can be interpreted as the volume under the curve on the area A (as long as the function is non-negative).

But why is $\iint dA$ the area of region A rather than the volume under $\ f(x) = 1 $ on the region A?

When I do the calculation, I know that it's the area of region A but I don't understand perfectly.

Comment: The key words here are "can be interpreted." There is nothing in mathematics to say a double integral _must be_ interpreted as a volume between a surface and a region on a coordinate plane.

Comment: Intuitively, it's because the derivative of area with respect to area is 1. The hard part is figuring out what "the derivative with respect to area" should be.  Of course the area of a region $A$ is also the volume of a region of uniform height 1 over the region $A$.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of this integral as the volume of a prism of uniform height $1$ above the base $A$. The volume of a prism is just the product of the height and the area of the base.

If you wrote this out formally with units of length for the three axes then the integral would have units $\text{length}^3$ while the area of $A$ would have units $\text{length}^2$, so they would not be *exactly* the same thing.

Comment: With regard to the units, to get the area of a base of a prism, you divide the volume by the height. From $L^3/L$ you get units of dimension $L^2,$ as desired. Of course if you don't use units at all then you don't even need to think about this.